# Как взять часть строки между двух символов?

Tags: строки, ruby

Есть строка:

```rb
str = "Donna W (ONE-ADMIN)"
```

Мне нужно оставить только `ONE-ADMIN`
Как вытащить часть строки между скобками?

Comment: [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, но для руби похоже нет решения :)

Comment: @NowhereMan, ага, и ещё для нескольких тысяч языков программирования. ведь для каждого языка требуется своё собственное, оригинальное, и ни на что не похожее решение.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Здесь вопрос не о тысячах абстрактных языков, а об одном конкретном

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать регулярку `/\(([^)]*)\)/`, в которой следует взять содержимое первой группы:

```rb
str = "Donna W (ONE-ADMIN)"

subs = str[/\(([^)]*)\)/, 1]

print subs
# => ONE-ADMIN
```

Можно воспользоваться поиском по индексу, но тогда лучше предварительно проверить, содержит ли строка пару скобок:

```rb
subs2 = str['('] && str[')'] ? str[str.index('(') + 1..str.index(')') - 1] : ''

print subs2
# => ONE-ADMIN
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашел методом тыка

```
str.slice!(/\(.*\)/)[1..-2]
```